# Write.table loop in R

Tags: r, loops, write.table

I want to create 1854 files with the name of the gene ID, specified in good_geneIDs_md25_missing, containing the list of samples IDs, specified in names. Names is a data frame with 1854 obs. of 1 variable, each row contains my sample IDs. good_geneIDs_md25_missing is a data frame with 1854 obs. of 1 variable, each row contains gene IDS.

This is my code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(names)){
  myfile<-paste0(good_geneIDs_md25_missing[i,], "_", "IDs")
  write.table(names[i,1],myfile, sep="\t", col.names = FALSE, row.names=FALSE, 
quote = FALSE)
}
```

But when I run it I got this warning message.

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'cluster_20833::chr1:46426022-46427420_IDs': Invalid argument
```

Comment: ok.. can you write in the directory you are in? this is really weird. or is cluster_20833::chr1:46426022-46427420_IDs a directory?

Comment: Can you please provide an reproducible example? I have no idea what the dataframes look like. So therefore,it is unclear for me whether you have an file extension somewhere. Because thise kind of error does make somewhat sense if you are lacking a .csv or other extension. But it also might be something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just found out wha was the problem, and it was as simple as R does not allow to create files whose name contains :